# How can I protect the plywood base of a tile table against the weather?

Tags: outdoor, plywood, tiling

HI  I want to make a small table for the patio and will put tiles on top.  what is the best way to preserve the wood on all sides before I tile it.

Thankyou

Comment: Will you bond the tiles to the plywood or just rest them on it?

Answer (score 3):

You may consider not using plywood at all. Once you frame the table, user cement backer board with a decoupling layer since those are the preferred substrates for tile.

Then you will have much fewer concerns about moisture, because the tile will be properly bonded, and provide its own waterproofing layer over the wood framing.

Answer (score 0):

CDX grade plywood is fine for outdoor use, the glue is waterproof so the plywood will not delaminate over time, you can expect it to last at least 25 years. I would put a preservative coating on all surfaces prior to the tile cement, paying added attention to the cut edges.

Comment: I would suggest a waterproof membrane  like is used in showers